# OSX Style global Menu in Plasma 5 (how to show pcmanfm_menu in global menu in plasma while in --desktop mode)?

Tags: macosx, plasma, globalmenu, pcmanfm-qt

I use pcmanfm-qt in plasma in "--desktop" mode, so that pcmanfm-qt "becomes" the desktop. Now i want pcmanfm's menu to be exposed to global menu, while pcmanfm only renders the desktop but no window is opended.
How can this be done? What files in plasma and/or pcmanfm need to be patched and how?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: it is kubuntu 22.04

Answer (score -1):

What i found out so far:
There is a project - RavynOS- that aims on building a free, osx compatible OS.
RavynOS uses a filemanager called Filer, https://github.com/mszoek/Filer (It is forked from pcmanfm-qt).
This filemanager can also work as desktopmanager.
It behaves just like the osx-finder.
It runs on plasma x11 and wayland and it exposes its menu to global menu while all windows are closed and only desktop is active.

Filer still has two issues.
On x11 it would prevent plasma from logout or shutdown.
In a wayland session it would not autorotate the desktop correctly (but that is  important only if running on a convertible or tablet)

Comment: The Autorotation Issue in wayland can be solved by starting filer with  QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb filer-qt

Comment: The cancelling of KDE's logout process in x11 Plasma is still an issue.  Each time you want to shutdown or log out from plasma the notification "logout cancelled by filer-qt" appears.  A simple shutdown script in .config/plasma-workspace/shutdown would not solve the problem. I think i need some help here.

Comment: Solution found:

using the command:

'qdbus org.kde.KWin /Session org.kde.KWin.Session.quit'

to log out fixes the issue. 

https://github.com/helloSystem/Filer/issues/151

Have fun with filer and a OSX Style global Menu in Plasma 5